# Remix online IDE Crash

Tags: solidity

When I run these two contracts, I first deploy `habibconcert` and then `changer`. When I call `displayTickets_numbers`, the IDE crashes.

[image]

[image]

Here is the contract source code:

pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

```
contract changer{


       habibconcert firstObject =    habibconcert(0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a);

       interfacer public changers;

      function changeTickets(uint new_tickets)  {


       //   changers = interfacer();      

          changers.changeTickets_numberTicket(new_tickets);

        //  firstObject.tickets = new_tickets;
        //   uint updateTickets =  firstObject.tickets  = firstObject.tickets + new_tickets;
        //   return ( updateTickets);
  }


    function displayTickets_numbers()constant returns(uint){

               return displayTickets_numbers();
    }


    }




interface interfacer{


    function changeTickets_numberTicket(uint new_tickets);

    function displayTickets_numbers() constant returns(uint);


}




contract habibconcert{

      uint  public tickets = 6;

      address owner_of_tickets;

      uint constant price = 1 ether;

       mapping(address=>uint) public purchasers;

      function habibconcert()payable{

            owner_of_tickets =  msg.sender;
      }


                function  displayTickets_numbers()constant returns(uint){

                    return tickets;


                }






              function changeTickets_numberTicket (uint newtickets) {

                         tickets +=newtickets;

                   }











        modifier ownLycreature(){


            require(msg.sender ==  owner_of_tickets) ;

            //   && tickets == 0
            _;

            }



               function changeTickets_number (uint newtickets) ownLycreature{

                         tickets +=newtickets;

                   }




    function buytickets(uint amount)payable{

          if(msg.value!=(amount*price) || amount>tickets){

              throw;
          }

          purchasers[msg.sender] +=amount;

          tickets -=amount;


        // if(tickets == 0){

        //     //selfdestruct(owner_of_tickets);

        // }


    }        





}
```

Comment: I guess this should be filed as issue in remix github

Answer (score 2):

because you have this

```
function displayTickets_numbers()constant returns(uint){

           return displayTickets_numbers();
}
```

an infinite recursive call !!!

it will work if you write instead :

```
   habibconcert  in_h=new habibconcert();
    function displayTickets_numbers_()constant returns(uint){

               return in_h.displayTickets_numbers();
    }
```

Comment: don't forget to accept the answer if it solves you problem